# Javascript issue: can find element by tag name but not by id

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am using the filterrific gem in a rails 5 app. I want to access the form fields associated with filteriffic. I have javascript that references by id a field in the related form and it does not work. Note that the javascript I wrote for accessing the field if defined on ready.

In the firefox developer tools console after the page is loaded I can do this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input').item(0).id;
```

This returns "filterrific_with_visit_status".

However immediately following if I enter this into the console:

```
document.getElementById('filterrific_with_visit_status');
```

I get back null.

I have no idea how this could be possible. Does anyone have any pointers on what could be the source of this issue?

Comment: The only way it would be possible is if the IDs do not, in fact, match, or you're doing these operations at different times. You'll need to add a [mcve] to the question, we can't help you based on what's above.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Just want to note what it turned out to be, I tried Chrome and did not experience the behavior. Verified it was still broken in Firefox. Then I closed the tab in Firefox and started a new tab and the behavior went away. I must have had a corrupted browser environment.